# Software to monitor all disk writing

Tags: gratis, linux, monitoring

I am looking for a program that displays what processes (by PID preferably) write to what location. So for example if I saved a file in a text editor, it would display the timestamp, PID, and where it wrote the file. Here are some side-criteria.

- It does not have to be a GUI program
- It would be preferable, if the program was on the APT repository, or open source.
- It should run on OS X and/or Debian Linux

Comment: In real-time while the file is being written by the text editor, or after the file is written and the text editor is closed?  (After the fact Linux has no metadata structure in which to  save the PID (or name) of the bin that created a file.)

Comment: @agc Any one of the 2. Of course real time would be more convenient, but after written works too, as long as I get a timestamp.

Comment: Did you try `iotop`? If you don't like it, why not?